# Outputting contents of DIR command to file by specific extension

Tags: batch-file

I have the following command that I have in a BAT file:

```
dir /b /s /-p *.sas /o:n >"%CD%"\WIN_file_list.txt
```

The goal is to have a file that contains the full path of ONLY files with .sas extension.

The problem is that when I run the above script, it outputs everything with sas in the extension.  **The file contains all of the .sas files that I want, but also all of the .sasb7dat files that I do not want in the new txt file.**

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `findstr` to filter:

```
dir /b /s /-p *.sas /o:n | findstr /E .sas >"%CD%"\WIN_file_list.txt
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, 

Do you know why this script might work on two Vista/7 machines, but not work on an XP Pro machine?

Thanks

Comment: @newbie_dev: I don't have access to machines with ancient versions of Windows but I suspect the `/E` switch was added later. You can use `findstr /R .sas$` instead, I think.